# Parse 88 GB rdf with PHP

Tags: php, rdf, freebase, large-data

How can I parse an 88 GB RDF file with PHP?

This RDF is filled with entities and facts about each entity.

I'm trying to iterate through each entity and check for certain facts per each entity. Then write those facts to an XML document I created earlier in the script.

So as I am navigating the rdf, per each entity I create a `<card></card>` element and give it a child called `<facts>`. I run through all the facts on the entity and I take the ones I need and write them inside and as `<fact></fact>` element children inside the `<facts></facts>`.

How can I parse the rdf, extract the data, and write it to XML?

Comment: I've had a lot of luck using the [expat based event driven parser](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.xml.php) when processing large files. There it should be trivial to set the event handlers to output to the target xml data. Depending on the graph of the rdf it might make sense to push into a database as you read the document then select the facts back out when writing.

Comment: @Orangepill I would prefer to not use a data base. I know you said it is trivial, but I feel like I am 5 when it comes to this. Can you please post an answer explaining how and then I can choose that answer.

Comment: Post a snippet from your rdf file.

Comment: @Orangepill Thank you for your help. Here is the first few lines: http://i.imgur.com/k1nBSEn.png 

I don't know if that helps. The data is available for download and it much smaller as it is compressed: https://developers.google.com/freebase/data

Thank you very much in Advance!

Comment: @Orangepill I'm sorry if I am being impatient. I would greatly appreciate it if you could let me know if you can help me or plan not to. I added a bounty to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use an RDF parser.  Googling for a PHP RDF parser turned up lots of results; I dont use PHP personally, but I'm sure one of them will do the job of parsing RDF.  But make sure it's a streaming parser, you're not going to hold 88G of RDF in memory on your workstation.

Second, you said you need to 'iterate through each entity' that might be tricky if either they're not sorted by subject in the original file, or the parser does not report them in the same order.

Assuming that is not a problem, then you can just keep the triples for each subject in a local data structure, and when you get a triple w/ a subject different than the ones you've queued locally, do whatever business logic you need and write out the XML.  Might want to make sure you can't queue up so many statements locally that you'll OOM.

Lastly, I'm going to assume you have a good reason to take RDF and turn it into an XML format that is not RDF/XML.  But I you might reconsider your design just in case.

Or you could put the data in an RDF database and write SPARQL queries against it, transforming query results into whatever XML or anything else you need.

Comment: How do I know what is a RDF Stream parser? I found the easyRDF, but is that a stream RDF parser? Do you have any examples in PHP?

Comment: its called a *streaming* parser...you need something like SAX; anything that will notify you triple at a time.  88G is going to be in the ballpark of 100M triples, you'll never come close to putting all that in memory unless its a big machine.  and no, as I said, i dont work in PHP, so i dont have examples.  but google seems to turn up some possible examples.

Comment: Ah, thank you for correcting me. Yes, that is true. Ah, okay. I'm sorry for misunderstanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option would be:

1. use some external tool (probably something like [rapper](http://librdf.org/raptor/rapper.html)?) to convert the source-file from [Turtle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_%28syntax%29) into [n-triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-Triples) format
2. iterate file one line at a time via fopen+[fgets](http://docs.php.net/fgets) as n-triples defines strict 1-statement per 1-line constraint which is perfect in this case